# PHP's '===' operator

Tags: php

I have code as

```
$url = $_GET['q'];
$string = "search_text";
$pos = strpos($url, $string);
```

Then I use the following to check for the presence of the search_text in the URL. If it is present, I want it to hide the HTML fields

```
if ($pos !== true) {
  // Generate HTML elements
}
```

However it does not work. Basically, I want to hide certain HTML elements when search_text is present in the URL using the `'==='` operator for comparing the $pos generated during the strpos operation.

Comment: `strpos` never returns `true`, did you mean `=== FALSE`?

Comment: If you don't actually need the position, it's easier to use [`strstr()`](http://php.net/strstr).

Answer (score 6):

The [=== operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) means exactly equal. Meaning that it must be the same type as well as have the same value.

```
strpos($url,$string); // Return an integer
true; // is a boolean
```

An integer > 0 is == true, but not === true

Alternatively you could use:

```
$pos = strpos($url, $string);

if($pos !== false) // $string not in URL
if($pos == true)   // $string is in URL
```

Comment: `===` is the *identity* operator. +1 anyways.

Answer (score 6):

`$pos!==true` is exactly the opposite of what you want to test for: `strpos()` will never return `true`, but either a number or `false`.

Use

```
if ($pos === false)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`===`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) or [`!==`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) to check for true/false means that the variable you are checking will need to be a boolean (i.e. **only** true or false).

Comment: @Pekka `===` doesn't check for *only* booleans. It'll give you a result for `0 === '0'` as well.

Comment: @Linus I was answering in the context of his question(he was checking for a boolean value). I guess I could have been more descriptive in my answer, but if I added it now it would just be redundant.

Comment: @Linus I read it as correct because of this: "Using ... to check for true/false ..." it could be clearer put but it's not wrong

Comment: @s992 No. Revising your answer is never redundant. Being descriptive in answering a question on SO is *your goal*. People might cancel their down-vote / give you an upvote on revised answers.

Comment: @pekka If it was correct, you would have upvoted already. There wouldn't have been a "corrective upvote".

Comment: @Linus Are you saying it's not correct? Which is fine as well, but I don't see how.

Comment: @Linus When there's two answers in place that were entered while I was typing my answer that have the exact same information I would edit into my answer, I find it redundant.

Comment: @s992 Granted. But then there's always the option to either delete or revise. You chose neither and instead argue. Personally, I upvote answers from users having the lowest rep, albeit giving "redundant" answers that are - in a way - correct. Which I would have done in your case. Take it as giving an inspiring downvote to force your to revise the post. If you don't, it's cool with me.

Comment: @Linus I'm not intending to argue with you but rather explain my answer and the context of it. Anyway, these comments are getting about as redundant as my edited post would have been, so I will leave it at that.

Comment: @Pekka, upvoting to even out a downvote is silly. You just gave the person 8 rep to even things out. So how is that even?

Comment: @Petah wtf? Upvoting to even out a downvote *on a correct answer* is perfectly fine. The downvote is what was silly in that case. I still fail to see how this answer is wrong - care to enlighten me? I think you guys are just reading carelessly

Answer (score 0):

Add one confusing case: between != and !==

```
$bool1 = false;
if($bool1 != '') {
  echo "I thought it came here";
}
else {
  echo "Actually it came here";
}
```

Because $bool1's type BOOLEAN is different than STRING, so they are not comparable.

That's why echo "Actually comes here"; while if($bool1 !== '') returns true.